# PHP: Self submit form don't work with Rewrite Engine

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to submit a sanitized form using `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>` but currently using the RewriteRule it point to index.php cause the page url is index.php?id=some

The only way i can self send the form is using `index.php?id=some` as action but this change the url in the adressbar avoiding the RewriteRule

How can I do? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, had not found that question, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is working in this case!